# Java using logger to process external logfile

Tags: java, logging, error-handling

I have a java application which is connected through ssh to a client. The client has a .log file that I can use to return the state of the client (running/stopped/error/....) . The thing is, currently I am just using

```
   tail output.log
```

and I store the ouput in a String. I then scan for the messages I want using String.contains

But, is there anyway to use the logger package to scan the log file, so that it can automatically sort the last output ??

THX

Comment: What do you mean by logger package?

Comment: the client uses log4j, i was wondering if i could use it too to process the output.log

Comment: I think you can use this https://github.com/otros-systems/otroslogviewer/blob/master/OtrosLogViewer-app/src/test/java/pl/otros/logview/logloader/basic/LoadingRunnableTest.java, But if you just need to read a couple of words, it will be like killing a fly with atom bomb.

Comment: yeah all i need is to read like the last lines of the output.log, get the last log msg , and i guess it's around 50 words max